# Is there a way to disable the Mighty Eagle icon?

Tags: angry-birds

The new (today!) version of Angry Birds (at least on iPhone) *offers* the help of a new character: the Mighty Eagle.

If you fail twice a level, the Mighty Eagle icon appears close to the *Pause* icon.
Clicking on that ME icon brings the Apple *payment* screen, so that you can get the Mighty Eagle to help you on that level (never tried, but seemingly it crashes the whole pigs construction and - I guess - you get a 3 stars by giving 0.99 cents).

The things is, to get 3 stars by playing normally, requires to reload the level a number of times! Making that ME icon to appear all the time, and I don't want to pay - *cheat* - in order to get the 3 stars...

**Question:** Is there a way to prevent that Mighty Eagle icon to appear on the screen?

It takes quite some place, and the screen is already pretty busy...
And while I don't intend to use that ME option, the icon is anyway available from the Pause / Restart screen.

Comment: I want a solution to that, too, since it actually is exactly where I want to click the yellow bird for a dive hit -- it's so annoying!

Comment: You can just tap anywhere on the screen to make the yellow bird dive, not just on the bird itself.

Comment: @Nick I know that, but that big icon (iphone) being a big eye is pretty monopolizing attention :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This web page](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/2010/12/angry-birds-mighty-eagle-explained/) explains how the Mighty Eagle works.

The salient points are:

- You will not receive any stars or points from using the Mighty Eagle - your performance is considered in relation to a completely separate 'Eagle Score'
- It's not a one-use item - once you purchase the Mighty Eagle you will have permanent access to it. However you can only use it once per hour on levels that you haven't beaten yet.

So you could purchase the Mighty Eagle and then use it (without receiving any points or stars and thus not cheating), and the icon would presumably not be available on that level, or any subsequent unlocked levels for the next hour.

**Note** - I haven't purchased it myself, but after reading about it there's a strong possibility I will!

Comment: Thanks for the details. I actually just want the icon to disappear from the game screen - which doesn't seem to be possible. And i don't want the help of the eagle either..

Comment: @Ring0 I just bought mighty eagle myself and it is not "helping" you, it's a totally different play style. Some levels that are very easy using the birds have taken me days to earn the feather for the level on mighty eagle. And it does not affect your star score at all.

Comment: @Scott The real question is **How to make that "eagle eye" disappear from the screen?** It should be configurable, people who don't want to use it should be able not to have it displayed. I'm afraid the only reason Rovio *forces* it to appear, is to "encourage" people to purchase it and generate more revenue...

Answer (score 3):

As of now with the current version (v 1.5.0), No, there doesn't appear to be any permanent way to remove the Mighty Eagle icon from ever showing.

From what I saw, it shows up after the 3rd or 4th replay of a level. If you click on the icon, and then close it with the X, it will disappear, but then it shows back up on the 3rd or 4th replay of the level. I tried running in airplane mode as well, with the same results. There don't appear to be any menu settings allowing it to be removed or moved to another area on the screen.